# Spinner item selection not working and debug flags 'No such Instance filed' error

Tags: android, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I used spinner in my app. I am using it to let users pick a color from to change the colors of text view. But the text color doesn't change when I make color selection from the spinner. Can someone point me to what I am missing in my implementation?

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/sColorSelection"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/font_colors"/>

//Spinner to change the font colors
        fColorspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sColorSelection);


        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.font_colors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        fColorspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        //fColorspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        fColorspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                switch (parent.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        //leave it blank to set the color to the default color
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLACK));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.WHITE));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.BLUE));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.GREEN));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Yellow));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.RED));
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.PURPLE));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.ORANGE));
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        setFontColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.OLIVE));
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }


    private void setFontColor(int color) {
        tv1.setTextColor(color);
        tv2.setTextColor(color);
        tv3.setTextColor(color);
    }


<resources>
    <string-array name="font_colors">
        <item>Default</item>
        <item>Black</item>
        <item>White</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Yellow</item>
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Purple</item>
        <item>Orange</item>
        <item>Olive</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Update:**
When I debug the ItemSelectedListener I am getting "No such instance field 'fColorSpinner'". But I already have declared and instantiated the spinner.

Comment: In which method do you create the Spinner?

Comment: In Oncreate method. I tried to declare it in class level and instantiate it in Oncreate method and also declare it in Oncreate but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the view simply isn't updating its diplay; try calling tv.refreshDrawableState() for each tv.

Comment: thanks for your response. I called that right after I changed the color of a certain textview but it didn't change the color.